# how do i make 1 plotly chart consisting of different dataframes, I need help to add the right buttons as well?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, yfinance

Below is the starting code, dataframes and TA indicator. Using plotly to make all my graphs.  The dataframes are 'df' and 'd15'. I do have others but will keep it simple for the help.

```
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.graph_objs as go

#Importing my data
df = yf.download(tickers='EURUSD=X', period='1d', interval='5m')

d15 = yf.download(tickers='EURUSD=X', period='3d',interval='15m')

def Supertrend(df, atr_period, multiplier):
high = df['High']
low = df['Low']
close = df['Close']


# calculate ATR
price_diffs = [high - low, 
               high - close.shift(), 
               close.shift() - low]
true_range = pd.concat(price_diffs, axis=1)
true_range = true_range.abs().max(axis=1)
# default ATR calculation in supertrend indicator
atr = true_range.ewm(alpha=1/atr_period,min_periods=atr_period).mean() 
# df['atr'] = df['tr'].rolling(atr_period).mean()

# HL2 is simply the average of high and low prices
hl2 = (high + low) / 2
# upperband and lowerband calculation
# notice that final bands are set to be equal to the respective bands
final_upperband = upperband = hl2 + (multiplier * atr)
final_lowerband = lowerband = hl2 - (multiplier * atr)

# initialize Supertrend column to True
supertrend = [True] * len(df)

for i in range(1, len(df.index)):
    curr, prev = i, i-1
    
    # if current close price crosses above upperband
    if close[curr] > final_upperband[prev]:
        supertrend[curr] = True
    # if current close price crosses below lowerband
    elif close[curr] < final_lowerband[prev]:
        supertrend[curr] = False
    # else, the trend continues
    else:
        supertrend[curr] = supertrend[prev]
        
        # adjustment to the final bands
        if supertrend[curr] == True and final_lowerband[curr] < final_lowerband[prev]:
            final_lowerband[curr] = final_lowerband[prev]
        if supertrend[curr] == False and final_upperband[curr] > final_upperband[prev]:
            final_upperband[curr] = final_upperband[prev]

    # to remove bands according to the trend direction
    if supertrend[curr] == True:
        final_upperband[curr] = np.nan
    else:
        final_lowerband[curr] = np.nan

return pd.DataFrame({
    'Supertrend': supertrend,
    'Final Lowerband': final_lowerband,
    'Final Upperband': final_upperband
}, index=df.index)


atr_period = 10
atr_multiplier = 6.0

df = yf.download(tickers='EURUSD=X', period='1d', interval='5m')
supertrend = Supertrend(df, atr_period, atr_multiplier)
df = df.join(supertrend)

#15 Minute Indicator 
def Supertrend(df, atr_period, multiplier):
high = df['High']
low = df['Low']
close = df['Close']


# calculate ATR
price_diffs = [high - low, 
               high - close.shift(), 
               close.shift() - low]
true_range = pd.concat(price_diffs, axis=1)
true_range = true_range.abs().max(axis=1)
# default ATR calculation in supertrend indicator
atr = true_range.ewm(alpha=1/atr_period,min_periods=atr_period).mean() 
# df['atr'] = df['tr'].rolling(atr_period).mean()

# HL2 is simply the average of high and low prices
hl2 = (high + low) / 2
# upperband and lowerband calculation
# notice that final bands are set to be equal to the respective bands
final_upperband = upperband = hl2 + (multiplier * atr)
final_lowerband = lowerband = hl2 - (multiplier * atr)

# initialize Supertrend column to True
supertrend = [True] * len(df)

for i in range(1, len(df.index)):
    curr, prev = i, i-1
    
    # if current close price crosses above upperband
    if close[curr] > final_upperband[prev]:
        supertrend[curr] = True
    # if current close price crosses below lowerband
    elif close[curr] < final_lowerband[prev]:
        supertrend[curr] = False
    # else, the trend continues
    else:
        supertrend[curr] = supertrend[prev]
        
        # adjustment to the final bands
        if supertrend[curr] == True and final_lowerband[curr] < final_lowerband[prev]:
            final_lowerband[curr] = final_lowerband[prev]
        if supertrend[curr] == False and final_upperband[curr] > final_upperband[prev]:
            final_upperband[curr] = final_upperband[prev]

    # to remove bands according to the trend direction
    if supertrend[curr] == True:
        final_upperband[curr] = np.nan
    else:
        final_lowerband[curr] = np.nan

return pd.DataFrame({
    'Supertrend': supertrend,
    'Final Lowerband': final_lowerband,
    'Final Upperband': final_upperband
}, index=df.index)


atr_period = 10
atr_multiplier = 6.0

df = yf.download(tickers='EURUSD=X', period='1d', interval='5m')
supertrend = Supertrend(df, atr_period, atr_multiplier)
df = df.join(supertrend)
```

This next part is the plot which I think is where I need the help. I need to add 2 buttons and add these 2 charts to each other?
Button 1: 5m  (Shows 05m TF Plot)
Button 2: 15m (Shows 15m TF Plot)

```
#5 Minute TF plot
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=df.index,
                         open=df['Open'],
                         high=df['High'],
                         low=df['Low'],
                         close=df['Close'],
                         increasing_line_color= '#04b29b', 
                         decreasing_line_color= '#ff2d5d',
                         increasing_fillcolor = '#04b29b',
                         decreasing_fillcolor = '#ff2d5d',
                         name='EURUSD'
                         ))

  fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                     y=df['Final Lowerband'],
                     mode='lines',
                     line=dict(color='#04b29b'),
                     name='Bullish'
                     ))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                     y=df['Final Upperband'],
                     mode='lines',
                     line=dict(color='#ff2d5d'),
                     name='Bearish'
                     ))

fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False,
              plot_bgcolor = 'black', showlegend = False,
              margin = dict(l=10, r=10,t=10,b=10),
              paper_bgcolor='black',
              xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zerolinecolor = 'white', 
color='white'),
              yaxis=dict(showticklabels=False, showgrid=False))

fig.update_xaxes(
rangebreaks=[
    dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]), #hide weekends
    dict(values=["2015-12-25", "2016-01-01"])  # hide Christmas 
and New Year's
    ]
 )

fig.show()
```

This is the 15 minute tf

```
15 Minute TF Plot
fig15 = go.Figure()
fig15.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=d15.index,
                         open=d15['Open'],
                         high=d15['High'],
                         low=d15['Low'],
                         close=d15['Close'],
                         increasing_line_color= '#04b29b', 
                         decreasing_line_color= '#ff2d5d',
                         increasing_fillcolor = '#04b29b',
                         decreasing_fillcolor = '#ff2d5d',
                         name='EURUSD'
                         ))

fig15.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=d15.index,
                     y=d15['Final Lowerband'],
                     mode='lines',
                     line=dict(color='#04b29b'),
                     name='Bullish'
                     ))

fig15.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=d15.index,
                     y=d15['Final Upperband'],
                     mode='lines',
                     line=dict(color='#ff2d5d'),
                     name='Bearish'
                     ))

fig15.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False,
              plot_bgcolor = 'black', showlegend = False,
              margin = dict(l=10, r=10,t=10,b=10),
              paper_bgcolor='black',
              xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zerolinecolor = 'white', 
color='white'),
              yaxis=dict(showticklabels=False, showgrid=False))

fig15.update_xaxes(
 rangebreaks=[
    dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]), #hide weekends
    dict(values=["2015-12-25", "2016-01-01"])  # hide Christmas 
and New Year's
]
)

 fig15.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get an answer quickly, you will get a quicker answer if you put a more simplified code on it. Or, if you create a reproducible situation with sample data and code for graphs, you will have a better chance of getting an answer. To answer the main question of how to make each graph a button, you can use the stock price data from the official reference, draw three different stocks, and set the show/hide control for each to show For example, if you only have AAPL, set the others to False to hide them. That is simply the only setting.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['date'], y=df['AAPL'], name='AAPL'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['date'], y=df['GOOG'], name='GOOG'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['date'], y=df['AMZN'], name='AMZN'))

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type="buttons",
            direction="right",
            active=0,
            x=0.25,
            y=1.2,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label="All",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, True, True]},
                           {"title": "All"}
                          ]),
                dict(label="AAPL",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, False, False]},
                           {"title": "AAPL"}
                          ]),
                dict(label="GOOG",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [False, True, False]},
                           {"title": "GOOG"}
                          ]),
                dict(label="AMZN",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [False, False, True]},
                           {"title": "AMZN"}
                          ]),
            ]),
        )
    ])

fig.show()
```

[image]